# How can I assign the type of a primitive to a variable in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have the representation of columns in a data table, e.g.:

```
[
  {prop: "firstName", header: "First name"},
  {prop: "birthday", header: "Birthday"},
  {prop: "amountInAccount", header: "Amount in account"}
]
```

and a row would look like:

```
{
  firstName: "John",
  birthday: 1543926555,
  amountInAccount: "1000"
}
```

Depending on what type each column, in my UI I want to show a different widget. I would like to store the type definition in the column interface, without using an enum for the types.

I have tried this:

```
interface IColumn {
  prop: string;
  header: string;
  type: typeof string | typeof number | typeof Date;
}
```

so I could declare my column like this:

```
[
  {prop: "firstName", header: "First name", type: string},
  {prop: "birthday", header: "Birthday", type: Date},
  {prop: "amountInAccount", header: "Amount in account", type: number}
]
```

but this does not work because of `error TS2693: 'string' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here`

How can I properly achieve what I have in mind, without the use of an enum or storing the strings `"string"`, `"number"`, or "`Date`"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom type base of string values represent the primitive value

`type primitive = 'string' | 'number' | 'date';`

```
interface IColumn {
  prop: string;
  header: string;
  type: primitive;
}
```

this should work

```
[
  {prop: "firstName", header: "First name", type: 'string'},
  {prop: "birthday", header: "Birthday", type: 'date'},
  {prop: "amountInAccount", header: "Amount in account", type: 'number'}
]
```

Another way to use Number and String constructors

```
interface IColumn {
  prop: string;
  header: string;
  type: typeof String | typeof Number |  typeof Date;
}

const data : IColumn[] =  [
      {prop: "firstName", header: "First name", type: String},
      {prop: "birthday", header: "Birthday", type: Date},
      {prop: "amountInAccount", header: "Amount in account", type: Number }
    ]

 console.log(data.filter( i => i.type == Number))
```